# Multi-threading on python for running 2 inter-related threads simultaneously (or may be background processing)

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want VideoCapture function from opencv to work smoothly while processing frames from it in background. As processing requires 3-4 seconds so at that time capturing video hangs.
Hence, I need to run 2 threads, i.e., one capturing video and other processing its output and printing on screen.
My code till now:

```
age = None
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret == True:
        # do some processing (3-4 seconds)
        age = process(frame)

        fr = update_age(frame, age)
        cv2.imshow('hello', fr)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    else:
        print "error"
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hence, I need a way so that my 3rd line don't have to wait 3-4 seconds to update its frame, while processing frames and printing its output runs in background.

**More Clarifications(mentioned in comments also):**

- I don't want to separate my threads, as one thread depends on output (frame) of other thread.I just want to run my threads separately
- I am showing all frames on my screen using cv2.imshow(). Hence, I need every frame captured to let my screen look smooth (and not just hang on after every 4 seconds). And output of processing is shown on screen, i.e., once a output is generated it will remain there until next output is generated after 4 seconds. (It's like a person looking in camera and his age is showing on screen but if is updating after 4 seconds)

Comment: Due to the [dreaded GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/), multi-threading won't help you much here. You need multiprocessing and there is a lot of info on SO on how to separate your workers.

Comment: If you can only process one frame every 4 seconds, why do you need to acquire more than 1 frame every 4 seconds? Either you will accumulate frames somewhere and process them later, or you will drop captured frames without processing. Which is it please?

Comment: Hello? Have you abandoned this question?

Comment: No, Actually I am out of town. So will check the helplful replies later. Thanks for patience

Comment: @zwer I don't want to separate my workers, as one worker depends on output (frame) of other worker .I just want to run my workers separately

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am showing all frames on my screen using cv2.imshow(). Hence, I need every frame captured to let my screen look smooth (and not just hang on after every 4 seconds). And output of processing is shown on screen, i.e., once a output is generated it will remain there until next output is generated after 4 seconds. (It's like a person looking in camera and his age is showing on screen but if is updating after 4 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example with `multiprocessing` where you would capture frames and process them later:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

frame_data = 0

def capture_video():
    print('recording...')
    return frame_data

def process_frame(frame_data):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(frame_data)
    return frame_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        data = capture_video()
        p = Process(target=process_frame, args=(frame_data,))
        p.start()
        time.sleep(0.1) 
        frame_data = frame_data + 1
```

Example Output (removed a few initial recording... printouts for conciseness):

```
recording...
recording...
recording...
recording...
recording...
recording...
0
recording...
1
recording...
2
recording...
3
recording...
4
recording...
```

Comment: This will continuously start 10 new processes each second which can never catch up with the acquisition unless it stops and will each take more and more RAM. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in that case, 0.1 would need to be 4 (assuming the operation takes 4 sec) instead which defeats the point, so the above code isn't going to solve the issue. Maybe another solution could be to have as the camera is capturing video, to store frames in a queue and have a set of processes operate on the frames. Frames could be dropped from processing if the queue reaches capacity. When a process finishes the operation, it would then take the next frame off the queue.

Comment: It's ok, it's not your problem! The OP needs to be clearer about his intentions.